# How to install TermKit on Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

The [following guide](http://blog.easytech.com.ar/2011/05/21/playing-with-termkit-with-chrome/) seems severely out of date now, and the author does not reply to user questions, so I ask you is there any other step-by-step guide for this?

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble as well, and started looking at the forks that have the most recent activity. The following fork worked for me. I cloned the repo and followed the directions in the Readme. The only differences were that the main script is called Node/server.js and I had to modify the Linux/termkit script to reference python2.7 explicitly. It's still clearly a work in progress, but at least I can start to hack meaningfully on it now.

https://github.com/colinmarc/TermKit

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/termkit-is-terminal-reimagined-install.html) one seems to be newer, if you have any problems, post the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it contains exactly the same instructions like the one above. There is a multitude of problems because if you follow the instructions it will just download the latest versions. And for example Node.js has gained three **major versions** since.

I'm trying to unravel this version hell. My current problem is that TermKit requires v1.2 of *connect*, but those versions were wiped out of NPM's repos. The closest is 1.7 and I guess that's the reason why I have session problems.